# I would like to add the following lines to the /etc/apt/sources.list.d

Tags: directory, ham-radio

There is a program named "Freedv" which is a ham radio program that uses the sound card to digitally modulate the voice carrier.

To run this program on Ubuntu 12.04, the literature states that one must add the following lines to the `/etc/apt/sources.list`  (in my computer this file is actually a directly called `etc/apt/sources.list.d`)

Here are the lines to add:

```
deb http://files.freedv.org/debian/ precise main
deb-src http://files.freedv.org/debian/ precise main
```

How should I go about this?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this way.  Open System Settings, and click on Software & Updates, and add the following lines as shown in the images below.

```
deb http://files.freedv.org/debian/ precise main
deb-src http://files.freedv.org/debian/ precise main
```

[image]

You may be asked for your password.

[image]